# How to allow only specific fingerprint in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

i am building an app where i want to allow only specific fingerprint per device. the fingerprint which is the original and genuine. Is there any method to implement this idea maybe convert into a number that i can store in database and match it whenever needed

Answer (score 2):

Several things about your question.

You can use a crypto key that is generated based on the current fingerprints enrolled in the device.

You need to put into the initializer:

```
 val builder =
            KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(keyName, KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC) //
                .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7) //
                .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true) //
                .setInvalidatedByBiometricEnrollment(true) //
val keyGenParameterSpec = builder.build()
    keyGenerator.init(keyGenParameterSpec)
 val key = keyGenerator.generateKey()
```

The key is stored in the AndroidKeyStore for later use.
The key that is generated is now usable in the following ways:

1. new fingerprints that were added after you used this, would make whatever you did before, to be useless to the user
2. You are not allowed access to any of the fingerprint data. - the only thing that you get is one of the following: The authentication was successful or not , and the option to use a cipher/mac/signature that can only be used once after the user has given their finger print authentication (each time to be used need to give a finger print authentication.
   So you will not be able to store *any* data regarding the fingerprint.